# Convert number to currency through directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to convert number into currency suppose if user enter 5 in textbox i want to auto correct it like $5.00 for that i am trying to write directive but no idea how to make it work as working on directive for fist time.

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular.module('commonModule')
    .directive('srCurreny', function (utilSvc) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {

                element.bind('blur', function (event) {

                    var val = element.val();

                    if (!utilSvc.isEmptyOrUndefined(val)) {

                        var transform = currency + " " + val.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
                        model.$setViewValue(element.val(transform));

                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });

})();
```

Comment: A filter is usually best for simple text manipulations, it even exists an [angular filter for currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Comment: But i want to change it as soon as user move to next field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

Set the `amount` in the `Controller` first.

```
angular.module('commonModule')
    .controller('aController', ['$scope', function (scope) {
        scope.amount = 5;
    }])
    .directive('srCurrency', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {

                function onChangeCurrency () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue($filter('currency')(ngModel.$viewValue, '$'));
                    ngModel.$render();
                }

                el.on('blur', function (e) {
                    scope.$apply(onChangeCurrency);
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="aController">
    <input type="text" sr-currency ng-model='amount' />
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/2pvw1st8/)**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the build-in currency filter of Angular, or, if that doesn't meet your needs you can create your own.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency