# displaying formatted numbers in a rails simple_form view with angular js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, simple-form, number-formatting

I have a rails form created using the simple_form and haml with Angular JS code sprinkled in it.  Angular is doing its job and computing the values fine.  However, I have a display problem:  I cannot display the totals being computed by angular and display it as a formatted value in a form control.

Here is the code snippet of the haml view:

```
    = f.input :total_amount, :label => 'Invoice Total', :input_html => { :readonly => true, "ng-model" => "grand_total" }
```

So the form_control 'total_amount' is bound to the "grand_total" attribute on $scope for Angular.

Everything is working fine computationally.  However, the total_amount input field is being displayed 'unformatted', e.g. 1655.3456.  I would like to display it as currency, e.g., $1,655.00.

I do not know how to do it.  I have tried to use the suggested approach of using number_to_currency rails view helper as shown below:

```
    = f.input :total_amount, :label => 'Invoice Total', :input_html => { :readonly => true, "ng-model" => "grand_total", :value => number_to_currency(f.object.total_amount) }
```

But since the total_amount field is blank to begin with when I initialize the Rails view, it has no effect.  Also, as the users change the nested form fields, the total amount is being updated dynamically by Angular.  The number updates fine, but formatting is an issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use currency filter from angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Because you are not using this field as input, try wrapping display value in something like span, then you can add filter like this

```
<span>{{total_amount | currency}}</span>
```

You can read about other options from the link

Or you can use directive from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051526/1805815